# how to block auto created subdomains from search engines which has another domain name?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel, robots.txt

I have hosted the BBBB.COM site in a shared hosting server, which has a root domain called as AAAA.COM, which is a wordpress site. So, my site folder is located at AAAA.COM/BBBB, which is not accessible directly nor by search engines.

My problem is - there is a subdomain created automatically, when I checked through cpanel, where it shows BBBB.AAAA.COM as a subdomain, which might be normal for a hosting server.

However, all my contents from BBBB.COM are indexed in Google search. When I click one of the search results, it shows BBBB.AAAA.COM as the URL in address bar, but shows everything from BBBB.COM.

I am not able to remove AAAA.BBBB.COM subdomain from CPanel as it shows that the subdomain has a link with the domain BBBB.COM.

I can't even block search engines from accessing the subdomain, as I have to use this code in robots.txt placed in subdomain:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And this code in htaccess file of the root domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots_no.txt
```

But, If I place the robot.txt with Disallow tag in BBBB.COM, then the whole BBBB.COM site will be deindexed by search engine.

Can I solve this or Do I have to contact the Hosting support?

Comment: You should do two things: 1. redirect all incoming requests for the “wrong” domain name to the correct one, and 2. use a `<link rel=canoncial>` in your documents to advise search engines as to what is the correct address for your contents.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, now I redirected the subdomain BBBB.AAAA.COM to main domain BBBB.COM - but, only the BBBB.COM domain is being redirected, not the entire posts in search results such as BBBB.AAAA.COM/233/post-title.

I don't understand about <rel=canonical>

Temporarily, I have added a Disallow/ to AAAA.COM (which is of no use now) to save my BBBB.COM, until I find a perfect solution. Thanks.

Comment: Your redirect should catch every incoming request that goes go the wrong domain – and send it to the corresponding address on the correct one. Of course, this will not immediately change what search engines link to – but it’ll take the visitors to the right place. The search engines will take a while to update their index with the correct addresses – and to help them realize what these are, you set the canonical URL. See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element